# Consulta GroupBy datetime con Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un problema al tratar de hacer un a consulta mySql usando Eloquent de Laravel.
Necesito contar la producción por día de un producto , ingresando dos momentos, en formato datetime (por lo que necesito el total de registros por día y la fecha, para luego presentarlos en el front end).
La consulta con SQL puro, resulta la siguiente, usando dos fechas como ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),created_at FROM myDataBase.myTable where created_at between '2021-08-20 00:00:00' and '2021-09-20 00:00:00'GROUP BY DATE(created_at);
```

El resultado es satisfactorio,(obtengo el mismo resultado si uso `DATE()` o `DAY()` pero no logro llevar eso mismo a laravel, estuve investigando y pude llegar a lo siguiente desde el controlador.

```
$produccion=MiModelo::select('*')
                                            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$desde,$hasta])
                                            ->groupBy(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'))
                                            ->count();
```

donde `$desde` y `$hasta` son los límites a consultar;

Pero me devuelve un solo registro y no día por día, como lo hace la consulta que está mas arriba.
Resuelto esto podré traer también los registros por hora...pero.. vamos por parte.
Desde ya gracias por su ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Como estas? En SQL no agrupo por año, si no por DATE sea por fecha (yyyy-mm-dd) si en lugar de DATE coloco DAY obtengo el mismo resultado, o sea, me sirve igual. Pero quiero llevar eso a laravel y no se como lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera.

```
$produccion=DB::connection('mi_conexion')->table('mi_tabla')
         ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as Total,DATE(created_at) as fecha'))
         ->whereBetween('created_at',[$desde,$hasta])
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
         ->get();
```

Con este código pude contar la cantidad de registros totales por días, es decir obtengo una producción día por día.

Comment: No olvides explicar brevemente qué hace el código (o cuál fue la clave en este caso) y aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.